# How probability distributions help a statistical analyst/data scientist

Tags: probability, distributions

How exactly the probability distributions help a statistician/data scientist in modelling/decision making?

Or how using distributions a data scientist derive any inference or make decisions when modelling?

I understand probability distributions theoretically but not sure how its utilised in day to day business operations. Some day to day business examples would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: It e.g helps to pick an appropriate loss function

Comment: @Michael M Can you elaborate or provide a link to literature where use of distributions to choose apt loss function is explained

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are referring to the standard probability distributions? In that case, an example would be the arrival times for a certain service.

For example, suppose that a hospital has a limited amount of beds to accommodate patients. The hospital wants to know how many beds it should have at any given time to make sure that the probability that they run out of beds is 0.01. In order to model this, we can look at the arrival times of patients. We note that patients do not influence each others arrival times and that during our period of measurement, say, 12 hours from 8 AM to 8 PM, patients arrive randomly.

Now, if we observe the number of patients that arrive say, every 5 minutes, we notice something very peculiar: it follows a Poisson distribution. Finding the amount of beds the hospital needs has now become incredibly easy, since from our observations we can obtain an 'arrival rate', which is the lambda in a Poisson distribution, and with this arrival rate we can compute this probability using this particular distribution.

Comment: Thanks Anon, example is very practical but assumption that addimissons follow poisson may be very simplistic. I had a doubt on application of poisson that it gives very low probability for (calculated using survival function) for higher values of the data. I posted it here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/61485/probabilities-of-a-poisson-distribution-not-making-sense/61498?noredirect=1#comment67004_61498. So the issue is in books we are taught that for admissions or bus arrivals or restaurant orders follow poisson but there are practical issues in Application to real problems

Comment: If you read my question you will understand my concern regarding application of poisson distribution and therefore decision  making based on poisson probabilities may be not the right thing to do. So question now becomes how to fit the right distribution and how much to trust the probabilities for taking business decisions